# Temperature Sensing with Arduino, PHP and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, arduino

I tried to copy part of the code from this guy website that I am doing the same thing as him. But in my database I could not get the value. here is the link [temperature sensing](http://scouris.wordpress.com/2010/09/10/temperature-sensing-with-arduino-php-and-jquery/#more-27). In my arduino, I have no problem received the value like this in serial monitor:  GET /getData/temp.php?t=-23.00

But when I go to my server to check the database, there is no data recorded. Here is some code I have in my arduino.

```
void getData() {

unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
unsigned long currentMillis = 0;
long interval = 8000; // 10 minutes (10*60*1000) 600000
  char strURL[70];

   EthernetClient client;
  // If there's a successful connection, send the HTTP POST request
   currentMillis = millis();
  if(currentMillis - previousMillis > interval) {
    previousMillis = currentMillis;

  if (client.connect(server)) {
    Serial.println("get data connecting...");


    sprintf(strURL,"GET /collecting/temp.php?t=%d",ambientTemperature);

    // EDIT: 'Host' to match your domain
    client.println("Host:192.100.1.45 ");
    client.println("User-Agent: Arduino/1.0");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;");
    //Serial.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;");
    client.print("Content-Length: ");
    client.print(strURL);
    client.println();
   // client.print(strURL);
    Serial.print(strURL);



  } 
  else {
    // If you couldn't make a connection:
    Serial.println("Connection failed");
    Serial.println("Disconnecting.");
    client.stop();
  }
}
}
```

Here is the php code inserting.

```
<?php
// connect to MySQL
mysql_connect('localhost','temperature','123') or die("Can't connect that way!");
@mysql_select_db('temperature') or die("Unable to select a database called 'temperature'");
if(ISSET($_GET['t']) && (is_numeric($_GET['t'])) ){
  // message from the Arduino
  $temp = $_GET['t'];
  $qry = "INSERT INTO tem(timing, temp) VALUES(".time().",'$temp')";
  echo $qry;
  mysql_query($qry);
  mysql_close();
  exit('200');
}
// no temp reading has been passed, lets show the chart.

$daysec = 60*60*24; //86,400
$daynow = time();
if(!$_GET['d'] || !is_numeric($_GET['d'])){
  $dayoffset = 1;
} else {
  $dayoffset = $_GET['d'];
}
$dlimit = $daynow-($daysec*$dayoffset);

$qryd = "SELECT id, timing, temp FROM tem WHERE timing>='$dlimit' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1008";
// 1008 is a weeks worth of data,
// assuming 10 min intervals
$r = mysql_query($qryd);
$count = mysql_num_rows($r);
$i=0;
$maxtemp = 60; // moderate weather now, but this can be
$mintemp = 0; // adjusted if needed. Just sample values for the moment.
$return;
$r = mysql_query($qryd);
$count = mysql_num_rows($r);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
  $tid=$row['id'];
  $dt = ($row['timing']+36000)*1000;
  $te = $row['temp'];
  $te = (($te+252-500) / 10); // easier to do adjustments here
  if($te>$maxtemp) $maxtemp=$te; // so the graph doesnt run along the top
  if($te<$mintemp) $mintemp=$te; // or bottom of the axis
  $return .= "[$dt, $te]";
  $i++;
  if($i<$count) $return .= ", ";// if there is more data, add a ','
  $latest = "$dt|$te"; // this will get filled up with each one
}
mysql_close();
// convert $latest to actual date - easier to do it here than in javascript (which I loathe)
$latest = explode('|',$latest);
$latest[0] = date('g:ia, j.m.Y',(($latest[0])/1000)-36000);
// End main PHP block. Data looks like this: [ [123456789, 20.9],[1234654321, 22.1] ]
?>
```

Comment: I cannot see any sql query with insert statement in your code !?

Comment: May I see the php? Also, either use GET or POST, not both.

Comment: @735Tesla yes, I posted it

Comment: @user2196728 I posted.

Comment: Can you add "print_r($_GET);" before line "mysql_connect" of your php file and send us the output ?

Comment: it gave me           Array()

Comment: So it seems that you are not passing any parameters to your php file...and the same with "print_r($_POST);" ?

Comment: can you send us the output of Serial.print(strURL); ?

Comment: GET /getData/temp.php?t=-32768

Comment: this has nothing to be with your actual problem, but do you think a temperature of -32768 is accurate ?

Comment: the temperature displayed on serial monitor is a little wierd. but when i print it out it accurate temp that I wanted

Comment: I got it... something wrong on my server address.  thanks guy

Comment: @user2196728 I still need help I got the value from database but can not display the graph on html by using flot

Comment: Other problem, other thread ! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your HTTP header is wrong.

a get request should look like

```
GET /collecting/temp.php?t=123 HTTP/1.0
```

or for http1.1

```
GET /collecting/temp.php?t=123 HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.100.1.45
```

the HTTP get request has to start with the GET line 
and end with a empty line;

if you want to add extra options to the HTTP request,
you must add them after the GET line, not before.

the arduino code should look like

```
sprintf(strURL,"GET /collecting/temp.php?t=%d HTTP/1.1",ambientTemperature);
client.println(strURL);
client.println("Host: 192.100.1.45");
client.println("User-Agent: Arduino/1.0");
client.println("Connection: close");
client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;");
client.println();
```

btw do you have a public ip address 192.100.1.45 
or is there a typo and should it be a private address 192.168.1.45